# What if message is not caught?

Tags: bpmn

I have two processes. Process 1 is throwing a message to process 2. However, process 2 is not necessarily catching the message at any time. See this image.

[image: Example]

What happens in this case? Will process 1 wait infinitely if process 2 never catches the message? Or will it just sent the message and will it never be received by process 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If process 2 Do not reach the receive message, it will just continue without any issue. Message from Process 1 will be send but not received.